# PlatformNotSupportedException when using EntityFramework and .NET Native

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, uwp, .net-native

I have an UWP (Windows 10) app which runs perfectly on debug mode (.NET Native disabled).

When I am running it on release mode, (or in debug mode with .NET Native compilation on I receive error on *return context.Set().ToList();* line.

```
    public IEnumerable<TMobileEntity> ReadAll()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext(database.DatabasePath))
        {
            return context.Set<TMobileEntity>().ToList();
        }
    }
```

here is an exception details

> {System.TypeInitializationException: A type initializer threw an
>   exception. To determine which type, inspect the InnerException's
>   StackTrace property. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException:
>   TypeHandles are not supported for types that return true for
>   ContainsGenericParameters.    at
>   Internal.Reflection.Core.NonPortable.RuntimeType.get_TypeHandle() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.CoreLib\Internal\Reflection\Core\NonPortable\RuntimeType.cs:line
>   262    at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.TypeInfos.RuntimeTypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(TypeInfo
>   typeInfo) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\System\Reflection\Runtime\TypeInfos\RuntimeTypeInfo.cs:line
>   398    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.SupportedMethodSpecifications.HasIndexSelectorParameter(MethodInfo
>   methodInfo, Int32 parameterPosition)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.SupportedMethodSpecifications.<>c__DisplayClass14.b__13(MethodInfo
>   mi)    at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass0`1.b__1(TSource
>   x) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\Open\src\System.Linq\src\System\Linq\Enumerable.cs:line
>   69    at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\Open\src\System.Linq\src\System\Linq\Enumerable.cs:line
>   199    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.NodeTypeProviders.MethodInfoBasedNodeTypeRegistry.Register(IEnumerable`1
>   methods, Type nodeType)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.NodeTypeProviders.MethodInfoBasedNodeTypeRegistry.CreateFromRelinqAssembly()
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompiler.CreateNodeTypeProvider() 
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompiler..cctor()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ClassConstructorRunner.Call[T](IntPtr
>   pfn)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ClassConstructorRunner.EnsureClassConstructorRun(Void*
>   returnValue, StaticClassConstructionContext* pContext) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.CoreLib\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\ClassConstructorRunner.cs:line
>   69    Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ClassConstructorRunner.EnsureClassConstructorRun(Void*
>   returnValue, StaticClassConstructionContext* pContext) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.CoreLib\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\ClassConstructorRunner.cs:line
>   86    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompiler.Preprocess(Expression query,
>   QueryContext queryContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   query)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Collections\System\Collections\Generic\List.cs:line
>   88    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
>   at TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.ModernMobile.Data.RepositoryBase`1.ReadAll()
>   in E:\Visual Studio Online\tiksn\Grocery
>   Checklist\Develop\ModernMobile.Data.UWP\RepositoryBase.cs:line 42
>
>   at
>   TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.MobileDataService.ChecklistItemsManagementService.<GetCurrentChecklistItems>d__5.MoveNext()
>   in E:\Visual Studio Online\tiksn\Grocery
>   Checklist\Develop\MobileDataService\ChecklistItemsManagementService.cs:line
>   62    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.CoreLib\System\Runtime\ExceptionServices\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line
>   66    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   186    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   155    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   127    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   320    at
>   TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.ModernMobile.ViewModels.ChecklistPageViewModel.d__15.MoveNext()
>   in E:\Visual Studio Online\tiksn\Grocery
>   Checklist\Develop\ModernMobile.UWP\ViewModels\ChecklistPageViewModel.cs:line
>   82    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.CoreLib\System\Runtime\ExceptionServices\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line
>   66    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   186    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   155    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   127    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Private.Threading\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   112    at
>   TIKSN.GroceryChecklist.ModernMobile.ViewModels.PageViewModelBase.d__46.MoveNext()
>   in E:\Visual Studio Online\tiksn\Grocery
>   Checklist\Develop\ModernMobile.UWP\ViewModels\PageViewModelBase.cs:line
>   102}  System.Exception {System.TypeInitializationException}

Comment: What is `DataContext`? Or to put it another way, if you're using Entity Framework, which specific version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It's not super enlightening but you can check out the source of the exception here: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/Internal/Reflection/Core/NonPortable/RuntimeType.cs#L262

At a high level, EF really just isn't ready to support UWP and being ahead of time compiled. I know they're working hard to get this support for the next update of the UWP tools.

This specific issue is that the current implementation of reflection in .NET Native is trying to use TypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom and has limitations vis a vis uninstantiated generic types. I think the plan is to correct this for the next version of .NET Native.

So I think you're probably just going to have to remove whatever in EF is hitting this issue. Sorry I don't have better news.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ef7

Open Properties/Default.rd.xml and add the following to the file

```
<!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->
<Type Name="System.Collections.ArrayList" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

Comment: Yes I did, for all concrete types of TMobileEntity.